# Pneumatic actuator capable to achieve 5m/s?

Tags: pneumatic, actuator

Is there a pneumatic actuator capable to achieve 5m/s and will be good idea for constant work? I know SMC have up to 3m/s, but I can't find faster.

Answer (score 1):

Pneumatic probably not. Something that fast would probably be belt driven servo, or linear servo such as LinMot.